# Option + S does not work on MacOs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, mac

I use the Polish keyboard, which has special characters, like ś, ż, ą, etc.

When I press Option + S, I expect "ś" to appear, but Chrome does not react to it at all. I don't face this issue anywhere else in the system (Skype, Safari).

Is it a shortcut? Can it be reassigned? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, but with another keyboard. It is fixed for me with the recent Chrome update 109.0.5414.87.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My Chrome is up to date.
Version 109.0.5414.87 (Official Build) (arm64)